# Navigation link in a website

Tags: asp.net

I have a login module in my webpage from where i want to redirect every user to a common page but their accessibility should vary on the same page,..some of them should get 10 links on that page whilw some should get 20 links on the same page...

Can anyone help me out...

Comment: Try accepting some answers - you've asked 14 questions and accepted none.

Comment: Also this is a bit too vague - how does your permission system work - are the menu items database driven, what determines who sees what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having menu items (values) in the database and while registering the user you can set the rights to access the list of menus and save it in databse. And if the user login you can retrieve those menu items from the databse.